# C# x509Certificate2 cannot be created

Tags: c#, visual-studio, certificate, x509certificate2

im creating a certificate via a byte array I make from an Apple .p12 file.

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(AppleCertBytes, ApplePassword);
```

this works fine and creates the cert,BUT, only when im on localhost.

When i build and publish my WebService to the server it doesn't work.

I placed logs wherever I can, and i noticed that the request sort of gone when running this row.

I get no response for server and sometimes even get `Err: connection_reset`.
When i debug the process i don't see any errors, and i thought maybe the `.dll` file was the issue bug I think i checked it for like 11 times with different logs and it seems updated at anytime.

***EDIT***
No exception is thrown.

Is there anything I'm missing here? ApplicationPool maybe, plugin or such?

***PLEASE NOTICE.***

I DON'T want any plugins that create the certificate, i want a possible results.
Thanks.

Comment: So just to be clear: that line doesn't throw an exception?

Comment: Yeah, forgot to say. no exception is caught.

Comment: Is the CA from that certificate in the correct store on that server? Does the identity used for that appdomain have persmission to access the certificate store?

Comment: please explain? i'm not an expert in certificates.

Comment: If you open that certificate locally does it show a cetificate chain? (you can find that on the certificate path tab properties dialog if you open a certificate). All certificates there as well as the issuer need to exist on the server as well...

Comment: there are not certificate chains

Comment: In which store is that certificate locally?

Comment: @rene i haven't created any store for that in the code if thats what you mean

Comment: If you open that certficate locally, does it show any messages on the information tab. I mean it IS valid?

Comment: no.. also, im not using only 1 certificate, my service is to give users an option to upload their .p12 file. i take the .p12 file (Apple) and creates a certificate with it.

Comment: open an answer with X509KeyStorageFlag on MachineKeySet and ill approve it. That was the only thing missing due to the CA, had to add authorization to open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use another [overload of the constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148422%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to store the private keys in the local computer store.

Your constructor should read:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(
                        AppleCertBytes, 
                        ApplePassword,
                        X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```